# firebase functions with top level variables state

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase functions defined in index.ts file. This is importing another .ts file as below

```
import * as CommonCode from './common-code'
```

The common-code.ts have few variables declared at the top like below

```
export let baseUrl = ''
```

There are two functions inside index.ts as follows:

```
exports.function1 = functions.https.onRequest(async (req:any, res:any) => {
     CommonCode.baseUrl = 'MyXXX.mydomain.com'
})

exports.function2 = functions.https.onRequest(async (req:any, res:any) => {
     var x = CommonCode.baseUrl
})
```

if i make a call to function1 which is setting value of baseUrl. And then make call to function2 then will function2 persist the value set as a result of function1 or will be blank?

my understanding is that it should become blank when i call function2 every time as i am not setting it anywhere in function2. But with some observed weird behavior looks like my understanding is not correct. So what is the expepected behavior here?

Comment: This explains a bit - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations

Comment: however like you, would like to see few experts thoughts here!

Comment: I tried to deploy it and it's finishing with error `Cannot assign to 'baseUrl' because it is a read-only property.`. How do you deployed this?

Comment: @vitooh not sure why you hit that. i have no problems in deploying this